# ng-repeat with slick js carousel

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and I have a hard time working with ng-repeat for js plugins like https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick and some other js modules (banner...)

```
  <slick class="slider lazy">
   <div ng-repeat="slide in slides"><div class="image"><img data-lazy="http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/images/lazyfonz2.png"/></div></div>
</slick

     <slick class="slider lazy">
       <div><div class="image"><img data-lazy="..."/></div></div>
        <div><div class="image"><img data-lazy="..."/></div></div>...  >> without ng-repeat, it works
    </slick
```

Maybe there's not enough time to wait for all images finish rendering before the slickJs takes action.

The directive does have $timeout (https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/blob/master/dist/slick.js) though.

Answer (score 7):

Seems to work without issues.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGNCFG1yASdvOQx8lBel?p=preview)

Maybe you can show the code in your src, not the result?

html:

```
<slick autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="500" fade="true">
  <div ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img data-lazy="{{image}}">
  </div>
</slick>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('demo',['slick']);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    "http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/images/lazyfonz1.png",
    "http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/images/lazyfonz2.png",
    "http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/images/lazyfonz3.png",
    ];
});
```

Comment: I don't think I can add or delete slides with your directive.

Answer (score 3):

You can add init-onload=true and data=(urDataArray):

html:

```
<slick autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="500" fade="true" init-onload=true data="slides">
<div ng-repeat="slide in slides"><img data-lazy="..."/></div>
</slick>
```

Source:
https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fakN9jW5h1ssWaiWaHeN?p=preview