# Angular-slick ng-repeat $http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I've been trying all the week end to display data (that I fetch with `$http.get`) in the slick angular carousel using `ng-repeat`, in vain...

I've read about the well known issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141858/ng-repeat-with-slick-js-carousel) and [here](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2).

I tried to use the `init-onload` and `data` attributes, in vain...

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="LandingCtrl as ctrl">

...

<slick init-onload=true data="ctrl.products">
    <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products"><img src="{{product.image}}" alt="{{product.title}}"></div>
</slick>

...

</div>
```

JS :

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('LandingCtrl',['$http', function($http){

    var store = this;
    store.products = [];
    $http.get('products.json')
    .success(function(data){
      store.products = data;
      console.log(data); //display the json array
    });

}]);
```

(`myApp` module is defined in my `app.js` file, I used yeoman to scaffold my project)

It would be great if you could help me.

Comment: well, I don't think that would work quite right, since `init-onload` is meant to wait until you have a variable for `data`, but since you pre-populate that variable with an empty array before making your `$http` request, slick isn't going to know it's supposed to wait.  does it work if you remove the line `store.products = [];`?

Comment: or, delay loading slick, as in the answer from @PankajParkar

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works as well as the Pankaj Parkar's method. Thanks to both of you I've understood an important point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `ng-if` on `slick` element. That will only load `slick` directive only when data is present just by checking length of data.

**Markup**

```
<slick ng-if="ctrl.products.length">
    <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products">
       <img ng-src="{{product.image}}" alt="{{product.title}}"/>
    </div>
</slick>
```

Comment: That's actually awesomely clever.  I never thought to use ng-if for that purpose.  Have to remember that one.

Comment: @jme11 Thanks bro.. Its just awesome but you need to follow `dot rule` while using this

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works as well as the Claies's method. Thanks to both of you I've understood an important point.

Answer (score 1):

I use standard slick carousel, not angular version.
You just have to wait for angular finish loading the data.
1 second or less is ok
For example

```
setTimeout(
        function()
        {
            $('#yourdiv').slick({
                autoplay: true
            })
        }, 1000);
```